# jquery not working with dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

In my HTML body I have this code:

```js
$.post('/GetManufacturers',(Data)=> {
  Data.Manufacturers.forEach(i => {
    $('#Manufacturers').append(`<input type="radio" name="Manufacturers" id="MF" value="${i}"> <label>${i}</label><br>`);   
  });
});

$('input[name="Manufacturers"]').change(()=>{
  console.log($("input[type='radio'][name='Manufacturers']:checked").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Manufacturers:</label>
<div id="Manufacturers"></div>
```

It adds the radio buttons in perfectly and they work fine, but when I select a radio button the .change() doesn't respond at all. I placed it inside and outside the document ready either or doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are dynamically added, your selectors won't pick them up since your selcetors have essentialy already queried the dom.

You'd have to change

```
 $('input[name="Manufacturers"]').change(()=>{        
    console.log($("input[type='radio'][name='Manufacturers']:checked").val());       
 })
```

to

```
 $('body').on('change', 'input[name="Manufacturers"]', () => {        
    console.log($("input[type='radio'][name='Manufacturers']:checked").val();       
 })
```

Comment: `$('body').on('change', 'input[name="Manufacturers"]', () => {        
    console.log($("input[type='radio'][name='Manufacturers']:checked").val();       
 })` Try that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case where you should use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in JQuery.

Elements are added after the content is loaded.

And in the beginning you're trying to bind an event to a selector which doesn't have any element in the page.

```js
const mockUrl = 'https://run.mocky.io/v3/48c668b0-291c-4704-b5ed-c14f5038b2c9'

$(() => {
  $.post(mockUrl, (Data) => {
    Data.Manufacturers.forEach(i => {
      $('#Manufacturers').append(`<input type="radio" id="${i}" name="Manufacturers" id="MF" value="${i}"> <label for="${i}">${i}</label><br>`)
    });
  })
})

$("body").on("change",'input[name="Manufacturers"]',() => {
  console.log($("input[type='radio'][name='Manufacturers']:checked").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <label>Manufacturers:</label>
  <div id="Manufacturers"></div>
</body>
```